# Group divs with css display: table-row

Tags: html, css

How can I group divs like tbody for tables? I´m using divs like tables with css. I used tags `<section>` and `<blockquote>` but it doesn't work. I want to group this:

```html
  <div class="divContenedor">
    <div class="divRow">    
        <div class="divCellText">
                Compatible <span class="aster">*</span>
        </div>
        <div class="divCellContent" style="width: 250px">
            <select id="soft"></select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="trPlataform" class="divRow" style="display: none">
        <div class="divCellText">
            Indique cuál <span class="aster">*</span>
        </div>
        <div class="divCellContent" style="width: 250px">
            <input type="text"  maxlength="45">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```css
.divContenedor 
{
  display: table;
  //border-color: #0063DC;
  border-spacing: 5px;
}
.divRow 
{
  display: table-row;
}

.divCellText
{
  width: 400px;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: right;
  vertical-align: middle;

  //border-color: #0063DC;
}

.divCellContent
{
  width: 550px;
  display: table-cell;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  //border-color: #0063DC;
}
```

but if I use section or blockquote the distribution appears bad.

Comment: You are missing the main parent div which should have `display: table`

Comment: sorry I forgot to put that part in this blog, but I have it.

Comment: You shouldn't use both `display:table-row` and `display:none` on the same element. To hide a table row, use `visibility:collapse`.

Comment: Anyway, to make elements behave like tbody, use `display:table-row-group`. See [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#table-display). But I don't know what you mean by "if I use section or blockquote the distribution appears bad".

Comment: thank you, with display:table-row-group works